# Should I store my files on another partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning, storage

I want to better organize my files in my computer but I have a question. In fact, I would like to store them all on another partition (E:). But is it a good idea? Is there any risk of loss, or will Windows be able to open and edit these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People have been doing this for years with the goal of preserving their files when they reinstall Windows. Nowadays it's much less useful since Windows 10 is pretty performant without regular reinstalls and has a reset feature which restores clean Windows without affecting user's files.

If you want to use partitions to organize files, go for it. Just remember about drawbacks. Your system partition will either be underutilized or will become full over time because you can't accurately predict how much space you exactly need for system and programs (+ this changes over time). You can adjust partitions later, but it's a lenghty and disk-intensive process with risk of data loss.

Another drawback is the fact that when you're moving file from one partition to another, the computer has to actually rewrite that file to the other partition. Moving files on a single partition is almost instantaneous because actual file data stays untouched, only its references are moved to a new directory.

Consider simply using folders as an alternative.

Comment: thank you, I am not gonna use partitions...